# Suggestions to motivate Team Members in an "Special Environment"?

Tags: team-management, motivation

I am working on my very first Project and act kind of the Producer / Manager or however it's called. The Project is an Videogame we're working on. It's an easy and dead Genre we're trying to revive. Because the Genre is relatively simple, we know we could make it with just the 3 or us. Even tho we plan to get an Artist on board as soon as the time comes. But that's not important to the main problem here.

Some more information until we get to the Problem:
The "Special Environment" is, that the Project is an Non-Professional (who could have seen that one coming ^^), and at the moment Non-Payed Project. All members of the Project will be paid as soon as it is making profit. So no-one knows if he will be paid at all, cause who knows if it will ever sell. The Project should take about 12-16 months.

The main problem is that I feel like my author doesn't seem too interested into the whole thing. At least not as much as I am. We are old friends and that might be an reason for that problem. She said she'd help out and work with me, but maybe I'm better off finding someone else.

Also we just started and she didn't even had time to show up in the first briefing, so I had to talk to her afterwards, that was some days later. Now I really want to start the project, and for that I need to discuss anything important she should know with her. but she seems not to find time at the moment. That makes me wonder if I should find someone else, who's a bit more interested in that thing than her, or if it's nonsense, since the Special Environment won't get me anyone to work with me.

Also I have a question to everyone, to you have any tips for me how to manage my Team in such an environment and how much of an "boss" I should give? Because I really don't want to look like an tyrant, trying to force people working on the project. At the end, they might never get paid for it anyway.

How much do you think can I ask of them, without being way too harsh?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question about project management; I wonder whether it would be better to migrate the question to workplace.stackexchange (where leadership in the workplace is specifically in scope) or to heavily edit the question to focus on the project management issues.

Comment: "How do I get other people to be interested in my hobby projects". Basically. You're not their boss at all. You need to make it fun. Maybe read up on how open source do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively what you're asking is how to manage a volunteer project. Sure, there's the possibility of pay-off at the end, but really right now everyone is volunteering their time. There's a fair amount of reading out there online and in books on the topic if you'd like to dig into the topic more, but the short answer is that you need to share what your needs are on the project and then ask the team what they feel comfortable contributing.

For example, if you need X amount of writing work done and the author only feels comfortable doing half that much work, then your team needs to talk about how to address that constraint. Maybe someone else on the team isn't as good of a writer, but is good enough for certain tasks.

Also, focus on the outcomes, not the tasks. If you need to accomplish a certain thing, the team may find a solution that addresses the problem within the time constraints of the everyone on the team that may be different than the traditional solution.

This is a deep, complex topic, but these two points should get you started in the right direction.